# Allow layout to occupy a % of screen space?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to allow a layout to occupy a percentage of screen space?

I've got 2 layouts currently one takes up about 130dip height and that's fine for most screens but when I switch to landscape the other linearlayout becomes barely visible on certain screen sizes. How would I insure that each of these are given equal screen space?

Comment: If all else fails, you can grab the screen dimensions and do it manually `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` Then just calculate the height available and set your layouts absolutely. Not recommended but if you have no other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set for each layout the same value for `android:layout_weight`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" 
                  android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#FF0000" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" 
                  android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've had some issues with `layout_weight` in a recent project. It seems that the weights only apply to the amount the container is allowed to grow, and doesn't depend on how much space the container already occupies. My solution was to modify it during runtime by calculating the widths based on the window size.  So generally it works, but trying to make a table view like implementation with a list view does not.

Comment: @smith324: Calculating sizes at runtime works in all situations, but it should be left as a last resort, in my opinion. I don't have much experience, so I might be (very) wrong.

Comment: @smith324: did you set the layout_height to 0dp? It calculates the "leftover" height as you say, so you lie to it and tell it that the height of each child is 0dp, as Gabriel did above.

Answer (score 1):

use `android:layout_weight`, here's the docs with [an exmaple](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html):

Here's a stripped down example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

That will make each of the 2 inner LinearLayouts take up half the screen.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_weight = "1"` in each of the items that you want to take equal space. This will make it work with whatever size of screen.

setting `android:layout_width` to be the same value for all will NOT work for all screens sizes.

... however using `layout_weight` will automatically distribute each equally regardless of screen size

Comment: if you want a percentage you should specify e.g. android:layout_weight = "25" and android:layout_weight = "75" to have a 25:75 split

Comment: One of the craziest aspects about the weight system is that sometimes it seems like the weight values are backwards. Just something to keep in mind